# Page returns 500 error after https redirect on google but works in browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to have google crawling my site but the search console says the site returns an 500 error. Even though it works as expected in any browser.
I've also noticed on facebook when I type the url in the chat the preview card shows "Ooops, something went wrong"

I ran it through httpstatus.io and it confirms it.
The page throws an 500 error after https redirect.

```
Status Code,Scheme,Host,Path
301,http://,rfa.is,
500,https://,rfa.is,/
```

I have other sites set up the same with no problems.

This is the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Remove public folder form URL
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/storage/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The URL is https://rfa.is

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is there a space allowed in `^` and `https://` like `^ https://`...?

Comment: have you checked the apache logs?

Comment: @UmairKhan I tried with out the space and then it just returns 500 error before the redirect

Comment: @Lulli240 try this site to found your error : https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ The result for your part of code : https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=cbaea258-b12a-52ac-9b11-d6b881aeb698

Comment: @hmg Website is on a hosting service and I dont think I have access to it. But I have another site on the same server and there are no porblems with that site.

Comment: @Inazo I ran it through that and all is green: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c2708a6a-42fe-535b-8bce-1b468d29dd0d

Comment: I think that the issue is not with `.htaccess`. The redirection works fine in browser but if you try to access it using command-line tool like `curl` in linux terminal, the `https` version gives `500` error. HTTP to HTTPS redirection `curl -IL http://rfa.is/` and direct HTTPS `curl -IL https://rfa.is/` generates `HTTP/2 500` in HTTPS version. There may be some server side restriction to only serve to some specific types of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the issue is not with `.htaccess`. The redirection works fine in browser but if you try to access it using command-line tool like `curl` in linux terminal, the `https` version gives `500` error. HTTP to HTTPS redirection `curl -IL http://rfa.is/` and direct HTTPS `curl -IL https://rfa.is/` generates `HTTP/2 500` in HTTPS version. There may be some server side restriction to only serve to some specific types of browsers.

*Quoted my comment.*

Oh I think I found out the reason.

If you provide `accept-language` header in request, regardless of its value, the result is `200 OK`.

`curl -IL 'http://rfa.is/' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9'`, `curl -IL 'http://rfa.is/' -H 'accept-language: ;'` and `curl 'https://rfa.is/' -H 'accept-language: ;'` works equally fine.

Same results with [GuzzleHttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) with PHP.

**Conclusion**: There seems to be some restriction / setting on server side that generates `500 Internal Server Error` if `accept-language` header is not present in request.